# win7 internet only works on 1 pc if other is turned on

Tags: windows-7, networking, home-networking

Me and my room mate are sharing internet with a TP-link WR-1043-ND. Whenever my computer is turned off, or my network adapter is disabled, my room mate has generally slow internet, and 3000+ ping to Google.com. The moment I turn my pc on, his ping drops to ~30. This problem appeared out of the blue a couple days ago. Any idea what can cause such behaviour?

Comment: Do you know if you or your friends machine have had any updates? It may be an option to use System Restore on both to a before the issue (although if this solves it, it won't explain why it happened)

Comment: Your title suggests that internet only works if PC is on, yet, your question states it's just slow. Which is it?

Comment: It would be nice if you can provide Network settings (at least IPv4 details with address, mask, gateway, DNS ) from both computers

Comment: The first step reset the gateway.  This will restore the default configuration.  Be sure to change the access point passphrase after you do this.